# When electricity goes and comes back, router wont start until network is manually saved

Tags: wireless-networking, router

When the electricity goes out and then comes back, I have to go to the app provided by TP Link (Tether) > Select Device > Select Network Status > Press Save and only then the router gets connected back to the internet. This means that the internet is there all the time but when I press save, only then it reconnects. Alternate way to do this is to go to the admin page > wan > Disconnect > Connect. Where could be the issue?

Note: I upgraded to the latest firmware provided by the official site.

Comment: Did this problem always happen?

Comment: Does your internet comes over DSL modem? Try to explore modems settings, there might be settings like "Keep connection alive", turn it on if it is.

Comment: Probably a race condition with your ISP modem. Your TP link starts up before your ISP modem which causes the TP link to get bad IP address information. I’m not sure if there is a fix for this. It’s kind of a combination of problematic software on the modem and the router. One solution would be to set a static IP on the WAN address of the TP link router, assuming it is an internal IP handed out from the modem. You might also explore bridge mode, or moving PPTP to the router (if applicable), etc.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes It always happened

Comment: @Alex Yes, I did experiment with that settings. Its PPoE btw.

Comment: @Appleoddity Yes, I do agree with your explanation of why it might actually occur. It makes total sense to me at least. Is there a way to keep auto-connecting after certain intervals until the network is back?

Comment: The two suggestions I made are the best route to resolve the issue. The modem should be in bridge mode if you are using your own router and the PPoE connection should be configured on the router. Work with the ISP to accomplish that.

Comment: @Appleoddity Please Post that as an answer with details if possible.